# If someone knows my external address and port, can public internet computer start a TCP socket towards my computer without router port forwarding?

Tags: networking, tcp, router, portforwarding

I'm trying to build a peer-to-peer game, where each player is both a server and a client with tcp sockets. The sockets can connect fine when I'm using local ip:s, but of course fails when I'm trying to use external ip:s.

But I'm thinking that the players should be able to connect to each other if they just knew the external address + port that the router assigns to them.
Setting up port forwarding is out if the question since I don't have access to the players routers.

I'm thinking of having a server in between, just to be able to read the external address and port of the players, and tell the other player about it so that it can connect.

But I haven't found any info anywhere if that's how port forwarding works. If computer A makes a request from a local address and a port to the server, and the router assigns this address + port to an external address + port, and the server tell computer B which address + port to use. Can computer B use that external address + port to connect to the computer A and start a tcp socket with it? Is there any way to know that this external address + port stays the same when another computer makes a request against them?

Comment: how do you do you handle about firewall and isp block some port? create some vpn server or tunneling for this make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

No, TCP doesn't work like that.

The source port that has been used to talk to the rendezvous server will be transient and specific to that particular initial TCP socket connection and can only be used as a destination for return traffic on the *same connection* from the rendezvous server, and can't be used by a third party to make new inbound connections.

The typical (only?) practical solution when NATs are involved and port forwarding is not available is to have that central server relay *all* messages bidirectionally between the peers.

Comment: He states 'each player is both a server and a client'.

Comment: @EJP that doesn't invalidate what I've said.   The one-off address/port pair that the central rendezvous server would discover from an inbound connection made by one peer is no use whatsoever to the other peer in trying to connect back.

Comment: @EJP I should qualify that - it's no use unless it's a crappy NAT / firewall that does happen to create stable outbound port mappings and then allows third parties to connect to them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that most people don't expose their PC directly to the internet. They have a router that has an external address. When you send a packet to their IP address, it is going to their router. The router doesn't know where to forward it to and what port to use without port forwarding.

So, getting everyone to enable port forwarding is out of the question, as it should be. A simpler mechanism is to have a server on the internet that you control. It has a firewall with port forwarding setup. The clients are just clients, they connect to the server on a port and send and receive info about the current status of the game. That way, everyone has real-time updates on their local game engine. Plus, this way is much easier to program and implement.

Answer (score 0):

Hole punching is what I was looking for.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)

Comment: This sort of hole punching only works if the NAT device permits it.  Not all do, since it's really a security hole.   If the NAT device is also functioning as a firewall it SHOULD NOT permit other third parties to make inbound connections to the temporary port that was opened by the outgoing connection.

Comment: In fact a decent NAT firewall shouldn't even let the _same_ remote IP (in your case the rendezvous server) make a new connection to that address/port pair, let alone any third party system.